# Connection property has not been initialized while running application from IIS 8

Tags: sql, asp.net, iis

While running my application through the source code, it works fine but while running from directly IIS then its giving me:
**"ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized."**

My Web.Config looks like:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME\SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajax" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Globals.cs file:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static string mycon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnStr"].ConnectionString;
    public static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
    public static SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    public static SqlDataReader dr;
    public static SqlCommand cmdDropDowns = new SqlCommand();
    public static SqlDataAdapter daProcessing = new SqlDataAdapter();
    public static DataView DvProcessing = new DataView();

    public static void Initialize(string CmdType, string CmdText)
    {
        try
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            if (CmdType == "StoredProcedure")
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            }
            cmd.CommandText = CmdText;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Login.aspx.cs file:

```
protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string strusername, strpassword, struserstatus;
            Globals.Initialize("StoredProcedure", "[sp_selectlogindetails]");
            Globals.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", txtusername.Text.Trim());
            Globals.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpPassword", txtpassword.Text.Trim());
            Globals.dr = Globals.cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (Globals.dr.Read() == true)
            {
                strusername = Globals.dr["EmpID"].ToString();
                strpassword = Globals.dr["EmpPassword"].ToString();
                struserstatus = Globals.dr["Status"].ToString();
                if (txtusername.Text.Trim() == strusername & txtpassword.Text.Trim() == strpassword & struserstatus == "A")
                {
                    //Public Folder
                    Response.Redirect("~/homepage.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    lblerror.Text = "Invalid Username or Password !.";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            lblerror.Text = exc.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: ...and where is the code that uses this connection-string? What is the complete error message including stacktrace, in which line is it raised?

Comment: i have updated the question, pls see now !

Comment: While running this application through localhost, it works fine, but while running from IIS, im getting error.